# If a nuget Package is .Net Standard 2.0 supported then can we use that package in asp.net as well as asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, migration

I am working on the migration of asp.net app to .net core , I have only list of packages(Not the code) used so need to know that if a package is .Net Standard 2.0 supported then the same package can be used in .net core 3.0?

Comment: Yes. Why not just try it?

Comment: I dont have code setup yet thats why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) indicates that:

`Net Standard 2.0` supports **>=** `Net Core 2.0`.

**Net standard** itself is compatible with `net framework` and `net core` at the same time, you only need to pay attention to the version it supports.

So if your packages support `net standard 2.0`, they will be installed into `Net Core 3.0` without any errors.